# Db constraint on foreign key

Tags: android, ormlite

I have a list of orders in my account entity. for that reason my order entity has a foreign key back to its parent order. what is the best way to prevent the saving of an order until its parent account has been saved first. I don't want any order to exist in the db without an account. 
To explain better
Here is my Order class

```
@DatabaseTable
public class Order{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private long id;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    private Account account;

}
```

Here is my Account class

```
@DatabaseTable
public class Account {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private int id;

    @ForeignCollectionField
    private ForeignCollection<Order> orders;

    public ForeignCollection<Order> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(ForeignCollection<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }
}
```

The thing is I am able to save an order without it's Account being set.  Is there a way to prevent this by setting some attribute in the Order's account field?
I have omitted some code but I know the above relationship is working ok because I can retrieve Orders Or1,Or2,Or3 for a given account A1 when I set the account field in each order = A1

Answer (score 0):

I am pasting the entire source code of the test database application. This should solve your issue.

I have an activity class that will provide u the UI to place an order and the supporting xml file, and a DbHandler class to perform database operations.

Here is the Activity code.

```
package com.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class TestActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private EditText accountId = null;
    private EditText orderNumber = null;
    private Button submit = null;

    private DBHandler dbHandler = null;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        setupUiElementProperties();
        dbHandler = new DBHandler(this);
    }


    private void setupUiElementProperties() {

        accountId = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.accountEditText);
        orderNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.orderNoEditText);
        submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
        submit.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void onClick(View v) {

        try {

            dbHandler.placeOrder(Integer.parseInt(accountId.getText().toString().trim()), 
                    Integer.parseInt(orderNumber.getText().toString().trim()));

            showAlert("ORDER PLACED SUCCESSFULLY");
            System.out.println("DONE..");
        }catch (SQLiteConstraintException ex) {

            System.out.println("SQLITE EXCEPTIOn: " + ex.getMessage());

            showAlert("THIS ACCOUNT DOES NOT EXISTS");
        }catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Exceptionn: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void showAlert(String message) {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(TestActivity.this)
        .setTitle("Alert")
        .setMessage(message)
        .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {}
        })
        .show();
    }
}
```

This is the xml code for main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/accountEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/accountNoLabel" android:inputType="number">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/accountNoLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/accountEditText"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/accountEditText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Account Id" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>




    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/orderNoEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/accountEditText"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/accountEditText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/accountEditText" android:inputType="number"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orderLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/orderNoEditText"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/orderNoEditText"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/accountNoLabel"
        android:text="Order No" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Submit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally the DbHandler class

```
package com.test;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabaseInstance_ = null;

    public DBHandler(Context context){

        super(context, "TESTDATABASE.db", null, 1);
        sqliteDatabaseInstance_ = getWritableDatabase();
        sqliteDatabaseInstance_.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        try {

            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT (accountId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)");
            insertAccount(1234, "xyz", db);
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ORDER_DETAILS (orderNo INTEGER, accountId INTEGER," +
                    "FOREIGN KEY (accountId) REFERENCES ACCOUNT(accountId))");
        }catch (SQLiteConstraintException sqliteConstraintException) {

            System.out.println("sqliteConstraintException: " + sqliteConstraintException.getMessage());
        }catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Exception in DBHandler.onCreate: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}

    public void placeOrder(int accountNo, int orderNo) throws SQLiteConstraintException{

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("accountId", accountNo);
        cv.put("orderNo", orderNo);
        sqliteDatabaseInstance_.insertOrThrow("ORDER_DETAILS", null, cv);
    }


    private void insertAccount(int accId, String accountHolderName, SQLiteDatabase db) {

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        System.out.println("db: " + db);
        System.out.println("accountId: " + accId) ;
        System.out.println("accountHolderName: " + accountHolderName);
        cv.put("accountId", accId);
        cv.put("name", accountHolderName);
        db.insertOrThrow("ACCOUNT", null, cv);
    }
}
```

Practically u wont be manually adding the Order Number(ORDER_DETAILS Table). This field has to be to be auto Incremented and entered into database.

I have added the insertAccount() in DbHandler as the "Account" table does not have any entries. Using this method i am adding an account with account id "1234".

This should be ur output:

scenario 1
account no: 1234 
order no: 453412

This entry will be inserted into the database as the account ID 1234 exists in the ACCOUNT table and a successful update alert is displayed.

scenario 2
account 2343
order no: 14523

This entry will not be entertained as the foreign key constraint fails. So you will get an alert saying "THIS ACCOUNT DOES NOT EXIST".

My database may not be same as u require but i hope this should be good enough to help u out.

USE SQLITEBROWSER to view data.

ur db file should be under.........

Go to file explorer -----> data ------> data ------> com.test -----> TESTDATA.db

Comment: Thanks for that,  it solves my problem alright but I wanted to avoid having any SQL in my app if possible.  I'm trying to solve this using an ORMlite solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay in answering.  Couple of things to try here.

Your `account` field on your `Order` should have `canBeNull = false` to make sure that the field has been assigned.

```
@DatabaseField(foreign = true, canBeNull = false)
private Account account;
```

This will throw an exception if you try to insert your `Order` without it having an `Account` set.  However, you could set the `account` file with an `Account` that has *not* been inserted into the database.  A way to solve that would be to make the `Account.id` field be an `Integer` object (as opposed to an `int` primitive) so it would be `null` if it had not yet been set.

```
// this is an Integer object so it is null if it has not been set
@DatabaseField(id = true)
private Integer id;
```

Then if the `Account.id` field has not been set, it will throw an exception if you create an `Order` with that `Account`.  Btw, it sounds like you probably want `@DatabaseField(generatedId = true)` but the `Integer` field would work for that as well.

Lastly, you could also override your `orderDao.create(...)` method to throw an exception if you try to create an `Order` whose `account` field was `null` or if the `account.id` field is 0.

```
// we have a custom DAO for this class
@DatabaseTable(daoClass = MyOrderDao.class)
public static class Order {
        ...
}

public static class MyOrderDao extends BaseDaoImpl<Order, Integer> {
    public MyOrderDao(ConnectionSource connectionSource) throws SQLException {
        super(connectionSource, Order.class);
    }

    @Override
    public int create(Order order) throws SQLException {
        if (order.account == null) {
            throw new SQLException("Order's account field is null");
        }
        if (order.account.id == 0) {
            throw new SQLException("Order's account field has a 0 id");
        }
        return super.create(order);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

@user965895: I did not see that u have tagged ormlite. I have no idea on it. The code i suggested was for SQLite. Android comes with built in light weight database SQLite that u can make use of.

Comment: No worries,  thanks for reply.  I am using SQLlite alright.  I ran the SQL you suggested "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON"  but it still allows me to create an order when the Account it references does not exist in the database

Comment: You answered this question twice?  This should be a comment.  Please remove.

Comment: @user965895: How do u know the values r inserted? r u using any browser to view data? if not use sqliteBrowser to view ur data. Did u try the cursor.getcount thing?? This should work(manual handling). But i would suggest using foreign key in built one rather than manual handling.

Comment: My test adds the Order object and then reads it back out. I have a testCase setup that expects an exception when I try to add an order that references an account which has not been persisted to the DB but my insert works fine :(

Comment: I have edited my previous answer and have provided complete source code. Hope that helps.